# Did any countries precede Nepal in introducing a 3rd legal gender?

Tags: nepal, lgbt+, gender

From [this article in The Scotsman](http://www.scotsman.com/news/international/nepal-to-offer-third-gender-status-1-2752129):

> Nepal’s government will begin issuing citizenship certificates with the category “third gender” for people who do not wish to be identified as male or female.

From the [Wikipedia article on Third Gender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_gender#Nepal):

> Nepal's 2011 census was the first national census in the world to allow people to register as a gender other than male or female.[19]

However, the Wikipedia article does not really discuss the aspect of a third gender in passports or ID-cards. If the information from The Scotsman (and other sources) is correct, Nepal will issue such certificates now. Are there any other countries that have done so?

Comment: Note: I'm not sure if "lgbt" is a correct tag here; feel free to correct if it isn't.

Comment: I've asked a [meta question](http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/q/231/97) about the "lgbt" tag.

Comment: OTOH, I think that either lgbt OR queer need to be aliased to one another.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Before:*

2005, **Indian** passport application forms were updated with three gender options: M, F, and E (for male, female, and eunuch, respectively).<sup>1</sup>

2009, Iftikhar Muhammad Chaudhry, the Chief Justice of **Pakistan**, ordered that the National Database and Registration Authority issue national identity cards to members of the hijra community showing their "distinct" gender.<sup>2</sup>

2011, **Australia** passport holders can use "X" as their gender.<sup>3</sup>

*After:*

2012, **New Zealand** passport holders can use "X" as their gender.<sup>4</sup>

Also, historical documents have mentioned more than 2 genders, such as:
Inscribed pottery shards from Egypt (2000–1800 BCE) list three human genders.<sup>5</sup>
Kama Sutra (c. 4th century AD) as pums-prakrti (male-nature), stri-prakrti (female-nature), and tritiya-prakrti (third-nature).<sup>6</sup>
the Manu Smriti (c. 200 BC – 200 AD) explains the biological origins of the three sexes.<sup>7</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> ['Third sex' finds a place on Indian passport forms](http://infochangeindia.org/human-rights/news/third-sex-finds-a-place-on-indian-passport-forms.html)
<sup>2</sup> [Pakistani eunuchs to have distinct gender](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/south_asia/8428819.stm) 
<sup>3</sup> [Getting a passport made easier for sex and gender diverse people](http://www.foreignminister.gov.au/releases/2011/kr_mr_110914b.html)
<sup>4</sup> [Information about Changing Sex / Gender Identity](http://www.passports.govt.nz/Transgender-applicants)
<sup>5</sup> Sethe, Kurt, (1926), Die Aechtung feindlicher Fürsten, Völker und Dinge auf altägyptischen Tongefäßscherben des mittleren Reiches, in: Abhandlungen der Preussischen Akademie der Wissenschaften, Philosophisch-Historische Klasse, 1926, p. 61.
<sup>6</sup> [Kama Sutra](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/27827)
<sup>7</sup> [Manu Smriti](http://sarit.indology.info/downloads/manusmrti.html)

Answer (score 3):

Australia added a third gender option, indeterminate, in its passports in September 2011, and as far as I know it's the first country to do so.

Sources:

- [Australians have third option for gender on passports](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/life/travel/travel-news/australians-have-third-option-for-gender-on-passports/article544980/)
- [New Australian passports allow third gender option](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-pacific-14926598)

Comment: 2011? Bah. SQL had "NULL" values for "indeterminate" [since 1975](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29)!

Comment: @user4012 That is an abusive usage of NULL. Please don't use it to indicate a valid value.